# Weights & Biases - How can I interpret the graphs when training BERT

Tags: bert-language-model

Can someone help me to understand the amazing graphs generated by Weights & Biases tools when you are training a BERT model?

[image]

How can I interpret the above image? I don't know what the dispersion grey means, nor if the concentration in the blue region is good or bad.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So those charts show the histograms of the gradients, per time step.

Take the leftmost chart, layer.10 weights. In very first slice at Step 0, the grey shading tells you that the gradients for that layer had values between ~ -40 and +40. The blue parts however tell you that most of those gradients were between -2 and +2 (roughly).

So the shading represents the count of gradients in that particular histogram bin, for that particular time step.

Now interpreting gradients can be tricky sometimes, but generally I find these plots useful to check that your gradients haven't exploded (big values on the y-axis) or collapsed (concentrated blue around 0 with little to no deviation). For example if you try train with a very high learning rate you should see the values on the y-axis go into the 100s or 1000s, indicating that your gradients are huge.

One final tip would be to focus more on the gradients from the weights as opposed to the biases as this can be more informative about what your model is doing.

Comment: thank you so much. It is clear now. I'm going to focus on the weights, but keep an eye on the others. It was great.